# how to install .net mongodb driver nuget package in xamarin

Tags: mongodb, xamarin, package, nuget

does Xamarin work with the .NET mongodb drivers? Tried to install the Mongo 2.2.3 package via Nuget but get the following error:

```
Adding MongoDB.Driver...
Attempting to resolve dependency 'MongoDB.Bson (≥ 2.2.3)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'MongoDB.Driver.Core (≥ 2.2.3)'.
Adding 'MongoDB.Bson 2.2.3' to mdb.
Could not install package 'MongoDB.Bson 2.2.3'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
```

Does anyone have experience with this??

thank you,

Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MongoDB.Bson NuGet package only supports .NET 4.5 so you cannot install it into a Xamarin.iOS project.

If you want to use MongoDB then you will most likely need to create a back end service that talks to MongoDB that your mobile app talks to over http.

There are third party hosting companies, such as [mLab](http://docs.mlab.com/data-api/), that provide a REST API to access a MongoDB.

Otherwise you could look at Couchbase as an alternative which has support for Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.iOS through Xamarin's component store.

Comment: not what I wanted to hear but thanks for the feedback!!